# Parse comma-separated string where some substrings are wrapped in double quotes

Tags: php, csv, text-parsing, double-quotes, delimited

Trying to parse a csv file that has all the data wrapped in double quotes, because there may be commas in the double quotes.

Looks like this:

```
$songs = '"1, 2, 3, 4 (I Love You)","Plain White T's","CBE10-22",15,"CBE10-22","","","CB",984,"","10/05/10"';

$regResult = preg_match( "", $songs, $matches );
```

I can't figure out a regex that will return the data between the quotes as the matches.  I'm sure there is some regex master that can help me with this.

Comment: Regex is not the tool for this.

Comment: Perfect.  Just needed the right tool.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you dont need no stinkin regex to parse a csv file in php.

see [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`str_getcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Comment: While correct, you could have supplied a short illustrative example. This way, the user does not have to leave the site and the answer is still usable in case the linked mirror of PHP.net is down.

Comment: I prefer to let the authorative documentation demonstrate basic usage of a function.

Comment: If there's DBCS characters, fgetcsv won't work correctly. I prone to use regex to parse csv data